# Java program to find all the unburned nodes when a node in binary tree is fired

Tags: java, binary-tree

Suppose a binary node is on fire, a random node (given) is burned, after 1 sec all the nodes connected to this node are burned, after 1 more sec, all the nodes connected to these burned nodes are burned.

After k seconds, which nodes are remaining?

[image]

In this binary tree, suppose node D is burned, after 1 sec, node B,E and C will start burning, after 1 more sec, node F and A will burn.After that G will burn, then next sec, I will burn and after that, H will burn.

Answer (score 1):

> In this binary tree, suppose node D is burned [<- 0 sec], after 1 sec, node B, E and C will start burning [<- 1 sec], after 1 more sec, node F and A will burn [<- 2 sec]. After that G will burn [<- 3 sec], then next sec, I will burn [<- 4 sec] and after that, H will burn. [<- 5 sec]

- [Input]
- Use a queue of nodes burning.
- Each second, burn all nodes connected to any node in the queue, you will have to use another list to save this. i.e. `isBurned[someIndex]` or `isBurned.leftNode.rightNode = true`.
- Output all of the not-burned nodes or other data.

This is likely too much. This is an incomplete model of how your answer might work.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test2 {

private static Character[] toArray (LinkedList<Character> L, char Char) {
    Character[] ReturnedList = new Character[L.size() + 1];
    for(int i=0; i<L.size(); i++) {
        ReturnedList[i] = L.get(i);
    }
    ReturnedList[L.size()-1] = Char; // It needs to be longer because it's used for the left and right
    //nodes, and they need an extra L or R to show they are on the left or right side
    return ReturnedList;
}
private static class Node { // for binary tree
    LinkedList <Character> spot = new LinkedList <Character>();
    Node left  = new Node(toArray(spot, 'L'));
    Node right = new Node(toArray(spot, 'R')); // left side and right side extention of tree, may stay as null
    boolean isBurned = false; 

    char name = ' '; // unused.
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55108957/java-program-to-find-all-the-unburned-nodes-when-a-node-in-binary-tree-is-fired/55109092#55109092
    public Node(Character [] args) { // either L [left] or R [right]
        for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++) {
            spot.add(args[i]);
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    Node tree = new Node(new Character[0]);
    tree.name = 'F';
    tree.left.name = 'B';
    tree.right.name = 'G';
    tree.left.left.name = 'A'; //tree is a node
    tree.left.right.left.name = 'C';
    tree.right.right.name = 'I';
    tree.right.right.left.name = 'H';
    tree.left.right.name = 'D';
    tree.left.right.right.name = 'E';

    //[set a node on fire with whatever you'd like]
    tree.left.right.left.isBurned = true;
    LinkedList <Character[]> Queue = new LinkedList<Character[]>();
    Character [] placeholder = {'L', 'R', 'L'};
    Queue.add(placeholder);

    int seconds = sc.nextInt();

    while(!Queue.isEmpty()) {
        ///////////Variables/////////
        Character[] X = Queue.pop(); // List of directions
        Node Y = new Node(X);
        Y = tree; // start here and go down
        ///////////Location//////////
        for(int i=0; i<X.length; i++) {
            if(X[i] == 'L') {
                Y = Y.left; // keep on going right or left.
            }
            else {
                Y = Y.right;
            }
            ///////////Burning///////////////

            //Think about it. How would you find a node that is connected to the burning node?
            //Don't forget to add newly burning nodes, and don't add nodes that have already burned.
            //The character array, X, is a way you could manage this with.
        }

    }

    /*
         F
        / \
       /   \
      B     G
     / \     \
    A   D     I
       / \   /
      C   E H
     */
    }

}
```

I do know there are likely better alternatives to parts of my question. (Like the placeholder array). Please tell me alternatives to them.